# Server control to add css file using application root sign ~ (tilde)

Tags: asp.net

Is there any server control that allows me to add a css file to my asp.NET page using the application root sign: `~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `runat=server`:

```
<link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/MyCssFile.css" />
```

Comment: @Naor: yes, you can make every html-control `runat="server"`. Then you can also reference them in codebehind. Here is an example with an image: http://blog.binaryocean.com/2006/01/07/ASPNETTildeVirtualPathsAndTheImageControl.aspx